# Como criar processos em c++?

Tags: c++, processo

Tenho um pouco de domínio em C até a parte de ponteiros(sou iniciante), tenho um professor da faculdade que passou uma questão sobre processos,tentei , mas não sei resolver:

**Questão:**

> Sabendo que os processos gerados pela chamada de sistema `fork( )` são 
>   encapsulados e protegidos, crie um programa em C utilizando a chamada
>   de  sistema `fork ()` para gerar um filho, sendo o pai um contador de 0
>   a 10 atribuído a  uma variável “A”, e o filho um somador da variável
>   “A” do pai mais “B = 10” do  filho, e imprima o resultado final da
>   soma de A + B através do filho. Utilize a API do  sistema operacional
>   para o compartilhamento de memória para a comunicação  entre estes
>   processos.

tentei fazer em c++(tenho mais afinidade), mas não rodou:

```
int main(){
    pid_t filho;
    int i,status;
    pid_t pid;
    filho=fork();

    if(pid==0)
    {
        cout<<"Sou o processo filho"<<"\n"; 

        for(i=0; i<10; i++){
            int a=i;
            cout<<i;                                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                                           

        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {                                                                         
        cout <<"Eu sou o pai , agora posso executar o meu código" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Editei e coloquei o que eu fiz na pergunta

Comment: Nem mesmo as versões mais modernas do padrão `C++` são capazes de manipular processos. `fork()` faz parte do padrão `POSIX`.

Comment: tem ideia de como resolve-lo em C?

Comment: Tu vai ter que usar `fork()`, `wait()` ou `waitpid()` junto com algum metodo **[IPC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_entre_processos)** para informar ao processo filho a variavel `a` manipulada pelo processo pai. Depois que se usa o `fork()` é criado um processo filho totalmente separado do processo pai, as variaveis do filho nao "enxergam" as variaveis do pai e vice versa, apesar de terem os mesmos nomes elas ocupam diferentes espacos de memoria.

Comment: Ah, mais uma coisa, isso nao tem nada a ver com C++ e sim com o SO. O **`fork()`** é uma chamada fornecida pelo Kernel, nao é uma chamada  da biblioteca padrao C++ (libstdc++), é importante entender esses conceitos.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro lembre-se que o comando `fork()` é um comando do UNIX, ou seja, você deve executá-lo em um sistema *nix. Usando o [Cygwin](https://cigwin.com) parece ser possível executá-lo no windows.

Assumo aqui que você está usando um sistema *nix.
Lembre-se que a biblioteca `<unistd.h>` deve estar incluída no seu código.

No `if (pid==0)` você deveria ter colocado `if (filho==0)` pois o comando executado anteriormente foi `filho=fork();` então o resultado ficou na variável `filho` e não em `pid`.

Aqui está uma versão modificada do seu código:

```
#include <unistd.h> // Esta biblioteca que define o fork()
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  pid_t filho;
  int i;         // A variável status não era utilizada
  //pid_t pid;      Nem esta
  filho=fork();  // Aqui ocorrerá a divisão dos processos

  if(filho==0) // Aqui estavo o erro, você não guardava o resultado
               // do fork no pid, mas sim no filho
  {
    cout<<"Sou o processo filho"<<"\n"; 

    for(i=0; i<1000; i++){ // Aumentei o loop para ficar fácil ver
                           // os dois processos ao mesmo tempo
      cout<<i << ' ';                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                           
    cout << endl;

    exit(0);
  }
  else
  {                                                                         
    cout <<"Eu sou o pai , agora posso executar o meu código" << endl;

    for (int k=1000; k<2000; ++k) // Coloquei um loop aqui
    {
      cout << k << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```